# How can I properly train a model to predict a moving average using LSTM in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm learning how to train RNN model on Keras and I was expecting that training a model to predict the Moving Average of the last N steps would be quite easy.

I have a time series with thousands of steps and I'm able to create a model and train it with batches of data.

If I train it with the following model though, the test set predictions differ a lot from real values. (batch = 30, moving average window = 10)

```py
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(batch_length, num_features))
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=False)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_labels)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="test_model")
```

[image]

To be able to get good predictions, I need to add another layer of TimeDistributed, getting 2D predictions instead of 1D ones (I get one prediction per each time step)

```py
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(batch_length, num_features))
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_labels))(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_labels)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="test_model")
```

[image]

Comment: predicting the last 10 time steps? you're trying to train a RNN to learn how to average?

Comment: Yes, it's a linear function of the last 10 time steps, so it should not be hard to do with few nodes, still the first version can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if your goal is to give as input the last 10 timesteps and have as a prediction the moving average to try a regressor model with Densely Connected layers rather than an RNN. (Linear activation with regularization might work well enough)

That option would be cheaper to train and run than an LSTM

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I was just looking to solve this problem that would certainly be a valid solution. In this case though, I'm more concerned with understanding how to create a working RNN (I'm going with LSTM but a GRU would work as well) to then use it in real world scenarios.

Comment: You usually use RNNs to predict something in the future. 
Train your model to predict the next step. (N+1) using the first N samples. (as an example)
After all, it all depends on what you want and especially how to train it.
Best of Luck !